# Process.Start from user machine

Tags: c#, .net, remote-desktop

I have a simple asp.net page that knows how to call some commands.

For example, i call mstsc.exe with specific parameters:

```
Process.Start("mstsc.exe", "/v:" + serverToConnect);
```

When i use this code on my local machine it works fine.

When i upload this code to an asp.net page on different server and try to click
on the button call this command, nothing happened.

I guess i need to somehow tell the page to call this command from the machine of the user who clicked this button.

Do you know what is the best way doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: this is not a good use case for a web application. I suppose what you are trying to achieve can be done using ActiveX control that is added to the browser (not sure if even then the security would allow RDP) but by all accounts it is ill advised

Answer (score 3):

Not possible.

Stop for a second and imagine the *havoc* unleashed upon the internet if any website could arbitrarily execute applications on any user's computer.

It works on your local machine because, by coincidence alone, when you're testing it your machine is *both* the server *and* the client.  The behavior is still the same, the application runs on the server.  When you publish it to another server, that behavior continues... The application runs on the server.

Whatever you're trying to accomplish, this is not a feasible approach.  It sounds like you want to install a client-side application on users' computers, which is a very different thing than an ASP.NET web application.

Comment: Yeah thanks..i guessed this is the problem.

Isn`t it a way to do it by user name and password or other secure way?

Comment: @DevTraveler: Only if that machine exposes that connectivity, which generally doesn't happen by default.  It would still require that you have code running locally on the user's computer, which puts us back to square one of having the user install something.

Answer (score 1):

Running this code from a web page will result in the process executing on the server. It is not possible to run this code on the local machine from an asp.net page.

All .NET code in an asp page runs on the server.